# XML data feed for wordpress

Tags: xml

im a fairly new web developer and one of my clients has asked me to generate a custom 'XML' feed for their existing wordpress website. I have been able to make a custom RSS feed but unable to find any help online for custom XML feed . My questions are:

1. What is the difference between the 2 feeds and can they be used interchangeably.
2. Can anyone please guide me how to make a custom XML feed. I followed the following link to create my RSS feed.
   https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-rss-feeds-in-wordpress/

Comment: What does the custom XML feed look like?  It's important to define what the deliverable will look like.  If all the content you need to create the deliverable is in RSS, you might just do a XSL transform on to create the desired result.

Comment: https://dubai.dubizzle.com/feed/dubizzle-examples.xml. This is a sample of the desired result

Comment: I see, that property data isn't in a standard RSS feed that lists articles etc.  You'll need to build a simple REST service, that queries your DB and returns the XML.  Look up how to build PHP REST services as a next step (sorry I'm not a PHP guy).